# Why does the compiler say "Static_cast from to which are not related"?

Tags: c++

Below is the complete code to my project (no code has been omitted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef enum{
    MAJOR_BUTTON_IGNORED_FIRST = 0,
    MAJOR_BUTTON_BLOCKS,
    MAJOR_BUTTON_IGNORED_LAST,
}MAJOR_BUTTON_TYPE;


typedef enum{
    BLOCK_IGNORED_FIRST = 0,
    BLOCK_ORDINARY_SMASHABLE,
    BLOCK_IGNORED_LAST,
}THING_TYPE;

class Datar{
private:
public:

    MAJOR_BUTTON_TYPE majorType;
    std::string majorButtonString;
    std::vector<THING_TYPE>thingTypes;
    std::unordered_map<THING_TYPE, std::string>thing2String;

    Datar(){

    }

    virtual ~Datar(){};
    virtual void initDatar(){};
};

class DatarBlock : public Datar{
private:
public:

    virtual void initDatar(){
        majorType = MAJOR_BUTTON_BLOCKS;
        majorButtonString = "MajorButtonNames::blocks";

    }

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    DatarBlock* db = new DatarBlock();
    Datar* blah = static_cast<Datar*>(db); //Compiler error here ****
    return 0;
}
```

At the line marked, there is a compiler error which says:

> main.cpp:62:19: Static_cast from 'DatarBlock *' to 'Datar *', which
>   are not related by inheritance, is not allowed

Why does the compiler report it as an error ?

EDIT:I am using Xcode 7.2 (LLVM 7.0) , C++ Standard Library = libc++ (LLVM standard library with C++11 support), C++ Language Dialect = GNU++11

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/TPGX82687). What compiler are you using?

Comment: @songyuanyao I am using Xcode 7.2 (LLVM 7.0) , C++ Standard Library = libc++ (LLVM standard library with C++11 support), C++ Language Dialect = GNU++11 .

Comment: Why are you posting the same question that you just deleted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785524/why-does-the-compiler-think-that-these-two-classes-are-not-related-by-inheritanc/

Comment: No errors, no warnings, works fine in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I deleted it because I thought I made a mistake, but it still wasn't fixed. So I created a new project so I could post the entire code, and since I couldn't find the deleted question I put a new question.

Comment: The full message appears in (vanilla) Clang 3.7+, 3.6 and below omit the "which are not related by inheritance" part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is invalid in C++11 as published (without DR 2148), where `std::hash` is not specialized for enum types (for an overview, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). It was accepted through libstdc++ 4.6 however (I do not have version numbers for `libc++`).

C++14 gains the desired specializations, but they are not implemented as of libstdc++ 5. They *are* implemented in libstdc++ 6, see [GCC bug 60970](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60970) and [DR 2148](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2148), and intentionally is available in C++11 mode as well. Whatever version of libc++ I am using *does* support them in C++14 mode only.

This is an example of why you need to look at *all* errors, **in order**, since earlier errors may render later errors completely meaningless.

Comment: The proof, compilation with `--std=c++11` fails, but compilation with `--std=c++14` succeeds.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès that's putting an awful lot of trust in your implementation. I prefer proof from the standard, or at least a site that is careful to refer to the standard.

Comment: From discussion with GCC maintainers, the existence of the DR means it *should* be acceptable in `-std=c++11` mode.